# ASP.NET MVC Each row dropdown onchange get data from database

Tags: jquery, html, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have dropdown in each row of my datatable, the content of the datatable is from tblaccount, then the content of the dropdown is from tblclient

**tblclient**

```
cid     cname        datereg
1       Client 1     08/07/2017
2       Client 2     08/08/2017
3       Client 3     08/10/2017
```

[image]
[image]

I need help, when I select an item in the dropdown, it must get the client id and date registered of the selected client name from the database and display it in the same row. 3 days and I can't still do this, please help.

**ListAccount.chtml**

```
@model MyProject.Models.ModAccountAndClient

<table class="table table-bordered data-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>CODE</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>CLIENT NAME</th>
        <th>CLIENT ID</th>
        <th>DATE REGISTERED</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Accounts)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.aid</td>
            <td>@item.acode</td>
            <td>@item.aname</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Clients)
                    {
                        <option>@item.cname</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**HomeController**

```
public ActionResult ListAccount()
{
    ModAccountAndClient list = new ModAccountAndClient();
    list.Accounts = _repo.ListAccount();
    list.Clients = _repo.ListClient();
    return View(list);
}
```

**ModConnection**

```
public List<ModAccount> ListAccount()
{
    var list = new List<ModAccount>();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblaccount", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        var param = new ModAccount()
        {
            aid = (int)rdr["aid"],
            acode = rdr["acode"] as string,
            aname = rdr["aname"] as string
        };
        list.Add(param);
    }
    con.Close();
    return list;
}

public List<ModClient> ListClient()
{
    var list = new List<ModClient>();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblclient", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        var param = new ModClient()
        {
            cid = (int)rdr["cid"],
            cname = rdr["cname"] as string,
            cdatereg = rdr["cdatereg"] as string
        };
        list.Add(param);
    }
    con.Close();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: where is your method which accept client id and date as parameter

Comment: You need to handle the change event of your dropdown list using javascropt/jquery and make an ajax call to a server method (passing the selected value) and return the data to the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke how can i do that?

Comment: I think you need to add class selector to your HTML `select` element & handle change event: `$(".ddlClassName").on("change", function () { ... })` and then create AJAX call with `cid` & `datereg` as passing parameters to action method with same named argument.

Comment: @PowerStar it's in the ModConnection then ListClient

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Can I have a sample code?

Comment: There are plenty of example on the web that will show you how to make an ajax call. DO some research and if your still having problems, show what you have tried. Your question is too broad as it stands

Comment: @Hanzou `<select class="ddlClassName">...</select>` is your first step to integrate select element with jQuery DOM. Then you can create `$.ajax(...)` with `data: { cid: [value], datereg: [value] }` & controller method must accept 2 arguments, e.g. `ListAccount(int cid, DateTime datereg)`. To explain further is still too broad of course.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i can't find anything on the web